# Adding a DeclarativeComponent in a UIComponent at runtime. Oracle JDeveloper 12c

Tags: javabeans, oracle12c, oracle-adf

I've been working in this project for abou a week and haven't find a solution to my problem. 
For testing purposes I create a simple new DeclarativeComponent which is a panelGroupLayout that contains 2 OutputText. After that I deploy the jar file and add it to my other Fusion web application libraries. 
I want to add this DeclarativeComponent in another UIComponent at runtime by pressing a button which contains the next code in the javabean:

```
`public void addComponent(ActionEvent actionEvent) 
{
    // Add event code here...
    createOutputComponent();
}

private void createOutputComponent()
{
    CuadroDeTextoComponent ui = new CuadroDeTextoComponent(); //This is my Declarative Component
    UIComponent parentUIComponent = getPglComponente(); This is the panelGrouopLayout in which i want to add my declarativeComponent
    addComponent(parentUIComponent, ui);
}

public void addComponent(UIComponent parentUIComponent, UIXDeclarativeComponent  childUIComponent)
{   
    parentUIComponent.getChildren().add(childUIComponent);
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(parentUIComponent);

}`
```

I have tried draging the declarative component and it works, but when I do it dynamically the component doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

For your component to display you may need to add a PPR refresh to it's parent element :

In your case :

```
public void addComponent(ActionEvent actionEvent) 
{
    // Add event code here...
    createOutputComponent();
}

private void createOutputComponent()
{
    CuadroDeTextoComponent ui = new CuadroDeTextoComponent(); //This is my Declarative Component
    UIComponent parentUIComponent = getPglComponente(); This is the panelGrouopLayout in which i want to add my declarativeComponent
    addComponent(parentUIComponent, ui);    
    addPPR(parentUIComponent); //Refresh the parent component
}

public void addComponent(UIComponent parentUIComponent, UIXDeclarativeComponent  childUIComponent)
{   
    parentUIComponent.getChildren().add(childUIComponent);
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(parentUIComponent);

}

public static void addPPR(UIComponent component) {
    if (component != null) {
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(component.getParent());
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, the panelGroupLayout is still empty. I add `System.out.println("Declarative Component: "+childUIComponent.toString());` and in the server log appear this: **Declarative Component: CuadroDeTextoComponent[oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude$ContextualFacesBeanWrapper@4ff7deb9, id=j_id5]** and everytime i click the button the id increments in 2